# Verlet Integration is blowing up my physics engine

Tags: c#, .net, xna, physics

I'm building a physics engine and i had some sort of "pseudo-verlet" thing going and i wanted to upgrade it to "real" verlet. So i found an article and set to work. After i added what i think is a good approximation, the engine doesn't work anymore. Can someone help me understand what i'm doing wrong?

My main physics body class's update, apply force, and apply impulse systems:

```
public void Update(float timestepLength)
{
    if (!this._isStatic)
    {
        Vector2 velocity =  Vector2.Subtract(_position, _lastPosition);
        Vector2 nextPos = _position + (_position - _lastPosition) + _acceleration * (timestepLength * timestepLength);
        _lastPosition = _position;
        _position = nextPos;
        _acceleration = Vector2.Zero;
    }
}

public void ApplyForce(Vector2 accelerationValue)
{
    if (!this._isStatic)
        _acceleration += (accelerationValue) * _mass;
}
public void ApplyImpulse(Vector2 impulse)
{
    if (!this._isStatic)
        _acceleration +=-1 * impulse;
}
```

**Edit:**
I've fixed it and it works like a charm, but i have two questions about the following code:

- Is the impulse application code correct, and if not what should it be?
- How do i change the position property so that setting it preserves the current velocity of the body?

Here is the code:

```
public Vector2 Position
{
    get { return _position; }
    set { _position = value;}
}
public void Update(float timestepLength)
{
    if (!this._isStatic)
    {
        Vector2 velocity =  Vector2.Subtract(_position, _lastPosition);
        Vector2 velocityChange = Vector2.Subtract(velocity, Vector2.Subtract(_lastPosition, _twoStepsAgoPosition));
        Vector2 nextPos = _position + (_position - _lastPosition) + _acceleration * (timestepLength * timestepLength);
        _twoStepsAgoPosition = _lastPosition;
        _lastPosition = _position;
        _position = nextPos;
        _acceleration = Vector2.Multiply(velocityChange, timestepLength);
    }
}

public void ApplyForce(Vector2 force)
{
    if (!this._isStatic)
        _lastPosition -= force;
}
public void ApplyImpulse(Vector2 impulse)
{
    if (!this._isStatic)
        _acceleration +=-1 * impulse;
}
```

Comment: Why not: _acceleration -= impulse; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as a reference to others... the verlet paper you are probably refering to is this: [advanced character physics](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15462-s13/www/lec_slides/Jakobsen.pdf) made by the team who created hitman and was one of the first to have ragdoll based physics

anyhow... the original code they used was:

```
 void ParticleSystem::Verlet() {
       for(int i=0; i<NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
             Vector3& x = m_x[i];
             Vector3 temp = x;
             Vector3& oldx = m_oldx[i];
             Vector3& a = m_a[i];
             x += x-oldx+a*fTimeStep*fTimeStep;
             oldx = temp;
       }
 }
```

and you are right that your code does a similar thing.

The one thing which always blew up my simulations was the use of a too big timestep.
Also, with this verlet integration, make sure that the timestep you use is constant throughout the game. (e.g 30 frames/sec for instance (so timestep is 1/30)) and doesn't fluctuate. If it does you should use the [time corrected verlet integration](http://www.lonesock.net/article/verlet.html) which accounts for this

EDIT:

answer to question2: to move your position (without changing velocity/acceleration) just update the position to the new position, and then as an extra step add the delta of this movment(so newPosition-oldPosition) to the oldposs, so this gets updated accordingly.

answer to question1: Impulse is the force applied to an object over a period of time. So your solution is not correct. The impulse would be that over X timesteps(or frames), you call your applyForce function with a fixed force.

Comment: I'm actually using http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/verlet/ as a base. What happens is that the particle doesnt really move at all (under a linear gravity force), and if i replace the `_acceleration = Vector2.Zero;` line with _acceleration = Vector2.Multiply(_acceleration, 1 - _linearDrag); it acts very unusually (particles start moving then when they hit a constraint that ties them to an area they go careening off the screen, i suspect their values get set to NaN shortly after).

Comment: The gamedev article cited has since moved to [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/a-simple-time-corrected-verlet-integration-method-r2200)

Comment: lonesock article for time-corrected verlet integration is now only available in archive https://web.archive.org/web/20150210025424/lonesock.net/article/verlet.html